# Hiding/showing div's children in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html, mouseover

In my site, I have a set of `div`s the have a delete option (which is basically a link). What I want is that the delete option -that is hidden by default- to be shown when the mouse enters the div and hidden when it leaves it. And if a div has children and the mouse is over one of it's children, then both the container and the child should have the delete option visible.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href=".." class="deleteOption">Delete</a>
    <div class="child">
        <a href=".." class="deleteOption">Delete</a>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <a href=".." class="deleteOption">Delete</a>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
    <div class="child">
        <a href=".." class="deleteOption">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So here's the JavaScript I've come up with:

```
$('div.container').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('a.deleteOption').show();
    $(this).find('div.child').find('a.deleteOption').hide();
});

$('div.container').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('a.deleteOption').hide();
});

$('div.child').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('a.deleteOption').show();
    $(this).parent.find('a.deleteOption').hide();
});

$('div.child').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('a.deleteOption').hide();
});
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE (even in IE 9) the delete option is intermittently shown and hidden. Is there a better way to do this using jQuery for every browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive this with pure css:

```
.container .deleteOption { display:none; }
.container:hover > .deleteOption { display:inline; }
.child:hover > .deleteOption { display:inline; }
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that CSS could to those things. It worked perfectly, even in IE6. Thanks!